# How to run multiple instances of a task in .net core worker service

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, worker

I have a .Net core worker service (which will be run as a Windows service) where I want to run multiple instances of a variable number of jobs. This is tricky to explain but here goes.

My service reads a number of 'Job Configurations' from a database. Each of these jobs needs to run 3 separate tasks, in parallel. So I have something like this:

```
        |- Task 1
Job 1  -|- Task 2
        |- Task 3

        |- Task 1
Job 2  -|- Task 2
        |- Task 3

        |- Task 1
Job 3  -|- Task 2
        |- Task 3
```

Now, I want all of these to run concurrently. However what I DON'T want is multiple instances of Job 1/ Task 1 running at the same time. Once Job 1 / Task 1 completes, I need it to run again, and so on...

I have tried various combinations of lists of 'workers', Task.Run and multiple worker classes, and can't get them to run as I would like - either Job 2 doesn't run until Job 1 is complete or I get multiple Job 1 / Task 1 instances spawning.

One example of an approach I have used is as follows:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("{Application} Service Starting", "File Sync");

        var TaskList = new TaskList(); //Gets the config for one or more tasks from DB

        foreach (var t in TaskList.JobDefinitions)
        {

            _logger.LogInformation("Adding worker thread: [{ThreadName}] for Job [{JobName}]: {JobID}", "UploadOnRotation", t.JobName.Trim(), t.JobId);
            _workers.Add(UploadOnRotation(1000, stoppingToken, t));

            _logger.LogInformation("Adding worker thread: [{ThreadName}] for Job [{JobName}]: {JobID}", "CheckMissingData", t.JobName.Trim(), t.JobId);
            _workers.Add(CheckMissingPimData(1000, stoppingToken, t));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(_workers.ToArray());
    }
}

private async Task UploadOnRotation(int delay, CancellationToken stoppingToken, JobDefinition jobDef)
{

    await using var connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
    //do all the clever stuff down here...
}

private async Task CheckMissingData(int delay, CancellationToken stoppingToken, JobDefinition jobDef)
{

    await using var connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
    //do all the clever stuff down here...
}
```

Has anyone any examples of how best to structure this code to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: `However what I DON'T want is multiple instances of Job 1/ Task 1 running at the same time. Once Job 1 / Task 1 completes, I need it to run again, and so on...`,can you explain more about this?